# Cannot stub jwt.verify()

Tags: node.js, jwt, sinon

I tried to write some test for my API so I need to stub jwt.veryfy method. 
 but there is some additional logic there so it didn't work. It returns
TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of null

```
 jwt.verify(refreshToken, configData.jwt.refreshKey, (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Token is not valid'
                    });
                } else {
                    let deviceId = decoded.deviceId;
                    let email = decoded.email;
                    console.log('device_id:', deviceId);
                    console.log(email);
                    let token = jwt.sign({email: email, deviceId: deviceId},
                        configData.jwt.secretKey,
                        { expiresIn: '24h' }
                    );
                    console.log(token);
                    res
                        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .send({accessToken: token, refreshToken: refreshToken, tokenExpiration: moment().add(24, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')});
                }
            });
        } else {
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
                .send('Auth token is not supplied');
        }
```

this is my test code where I tried to handle this

```
describe('LoginController(refreshLoginToken)', function() {
let body = {
    refreshToken: ' '
}

let req = {
    body
}
let options = {
    status: sinon.spy()
}
let res = mockResponse(options)



before(function() {
   sinon.stub(jwt, 'verify')

})

after(function() {
    sinon.restore()
})

it('should refresh login token', async function() {
    await controller.refreshLoginToken(req, res)
    expect(res.status.firstCall.args[0]).to.equal(HttpStatus.OK)
})
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? If you stub `verify` and you're passing in a function that the original `verify` runs then you'd need to stub running the callback as well. It's unclear what *precisely* you've done, since you don't say.

Comment: I simply wrote sinon.stub(jwt, 'verify'), I don't have an idea how to handle this. I'm new to this

Comment: I edited my post please check

Comment: `verify` does whatever it does, then runs your callback. If you stub `verify` then you must do something with the callback if you expect callback logic to be executed. Your stub needs to be a function that (at the very least) executes the callback, passing it whatever values are appropriate (e.g., `err` and `decoded` need to make sense based on the logic you're testing. When you stub something, if you need that stub to *do* something, then you actually need to write it.

Comment: Your code has syntax error. Can' help